# Single port route to different services

Tags: javascript, node.js, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

My question is: is [http-proxy](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy), [reverse-proxy.js](https://docs.belin.io/reverse-proxy.js/), or any other library(with exception of a web-server like nginx) capable of routing all requests that comes to the port 80 to another services based on the url?

If a request comes at the port 80 with that url `localhost:80/route1` I want to redirect it to the service at `localhost:3001`

If a request comes at the port 80 with that url `localhost:80/another-route` I want to redirect it to the service at `localhost:3002`. And so on..

To summarize it: I want to expose 1 port(80), and then route the request to other services based on the URL pattern from the request.
So far I tried this approach below using [reverse-proxy.js](https://docs.belin.io/reverse-proxy.js/) but it only works if the port changes

```
{
  "port": 80,
  "routes": {
    "localhost/test": "localhost:3001",
    "localhost/another-route": "localhost:3002",
    "localhost/another-route-same-service": "localhost:3002",
    "*": 80
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can. It's a very common requirement. In Node you can do it natively using streams. Here's a full working example using only the standard Node [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) library.

```js
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer();

let routes = {
    '/test': {
        hostname: 'portquiz.net',
        port: 80
    }
}

function proxy(req, res){
    if (!routes[req.url]){
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    let options = {
        ...routes[req.url],
        path: '', // if you want to maintain the path use req.url
        method: req.method,
        headers: req.headers
    }

    let proxy = http.request(options, function(r){
        res.writeHead(r.statusCode, r.headers);
        r.pipe(res, { end: true });
    })

    req.pipe(proxy, { end: true }).on('error', err => console.log(err))
}

server.on('request', proxy);
server.listen(8080);
```